# There is no linear operator $T$ on $\mathbb{C}^2$ st $(\alpha|T(\alpha)=0$ for all the vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

I have been able to prove this but my question is what does it signify geometrically?

Here inner product is the standard inner product. Does it signify there is no linear operator $T$ such that it can rotate the vector $\alpha$ in 90 degrees?Why does it happen? How do I generalize this?

Comment: Well I have been able to prove this .What is the geometry behind this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $\mathbb{R}^2,$ the rotation $T = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1\\-1& 0 \end{pmatrix}$ is the only solution, but it is easy to show that this does not work on $\mathbb{C}^2.$ I assume this is your solution, and what it shows is that, indeed, a ninety degree rotation does not map every complex vector to an orthogonal one. This is because the matrix is actually diagonalizable over the complex numbers (eigenvalues $\pm i.$)

Comment: -How do I generalize the problem for $\mathbb{C^n}$ - I think there will not exist any linear operator such that it holds true.I am not able to do the calculations. What will be the intuition behind the calculation?